# How can I disable ESLint from automatically running in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, eslint

I'd like to run ESLint when I save a certain file, and not have WebStorm automatically run ESLint in the background. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

1. Disable **ESLint** integration in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | ESLint**
2. Set up it as a file watcher in **Settings | Tools | File Watchers**. see [this article](https://medium.com/@netczuk/even-faster-code-formatting-using-eslint-22b80d061461) for some hints

We have plans to enable running ESLint on save out of the box, please follow [WEB-24452](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24452) for updates